# Remove cache/cookies Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, intune

So i want to remove the cache/cookies from edge,
with intune for non hybrid devices.

More specific,
every day around a certain hour or when you close the edge browser .

I couldn’t find a policy in intune.
In intune there is no option for sending a script every day.
Then i thought about exporting an xml file from schedular task with a powershell script that removes the cache and make from that an win32 app.

That works, but when Edge is started it won't work.
It is not an option to close edge.

i used the follow script for that:
$test = "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Cache"
Remove-Item -Path $test -Recurse -Force -Verbose #-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

Anyone who has an idea/solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear cache and cookies when close the browser, you can configure this policy [DefaultCookiesSetting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#defaultcookiessetting). You need to enable this policy and set the value to "Keep cookies for the duration of the session, except ones listed in SaveCookiesOnExit". It means to clear cookies when the session closes.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer Yu Zhou,
this works for domain joined devices
i want to do it for non domain devices,
managed by intune

Comment: @Eggeto I think Edge group policy can also work with Intune. I find this doc [Configure Microsoft Edge policy settings in Microsoft Intune](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/configuration/administrative-templates-configure-edge?bc=%2FDeployEdge%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&toc=%2FDeployEdge%2Ftoc.json), you can check it.